# Decode recipient email address mimeDecode.php

Tags: php, email, pear

I am working with the https://github.com/stuporglue/mailreader script which requires http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode/.

The script works great, however, I can't find the method to get the recipient's email address.

This is how I get the sender:

```
 $this->from = $this->decoded->headers['from'];
```

For the recipient I tried:

```
$this->to = $this->decoded->headers['to']; (seemed obvious)

$to_email = $this->to;
```

but $to_email is empty.

Comment: You can try doing a print_r($this->decoded->headers) and see if you find a clue

Comment: Thanks for your help in this. I was using the correct syntax: 
    $this->decoded->headers['to'];

I just had to use a global variable to access outside of the function.